# WP: problems with qTranslate styles

Tags: css, wordpress, qtranslate

I am using the plugin qTranslate 2.5.39 and wordpress 3.8.1.
I want to have a drop down with the flags in the header and as the [FAQ](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/faq/) points, here is my `header.php` code:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar">

                <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">

                    <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h3>

                    <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></a>

                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>

                    <!--<?php get_search_form(); ?>-->
                    <?php qtrans_generateLanguageSelectCode('image'); ?>

                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

            </div><!-- #navbar -->
```

And in my styles.css

```
.qtrans_language_chooser { list-style-type:none; background-color: red }
.qtrans_language_chooser li { float:left; margin-right:3px }
.qtrans_flag { border:1px solid #b6b6b6 }
```

I tried as well with `!important`, but didnt work.

The source code:

```
<ul class="qtrans_language_chooser" id="qtranslate-chooser">
    <li class="lang-de">
        <a href="http://link/?lang=de" hreflang="de" title="Deutsch" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_de">
        <span style="display:none">Deutsch</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="lang-en">
        <a href="http://myfavcolorismusi.byethost32.com/immtranslates/?lang=en" hreflang="en" title="English" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_en">
        <span style="display:none">English</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="lang-es active">ç
        <a href="http://myfavcolorismusi.byethost32.com/immtranslates/" hreflang="es" title="Español" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_es">
        <span style="display:none">Español</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul><div class="qtrans_widget_end"></div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT
Could it be a google chrome style managment problem? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in css file of your theme, try

```
#qtranslate-chooser{//style} 

#qtranslate-chooser li{//style}
...
```

Comment: The problem is still there. Please, see the attachment I added. In the console I see that the element class/id is not recognized

Comment: there may be mutiple .css files,  where do you put it? and you can also put it in the header.php <style>#qtranslate-chooser{...}</style>

Comment: I put the styles in the header.php and it worked! Thanks. Before I had the styles in the theme styles.css, where all other styles are. I will try to figure out which style sheet is qtranslate using. Thanks!